# Kernel error when trying to start a R Jupiter notebook using IRkernel

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I followed the IRkernel instructions on github but when I load up a new notebook it says that there is a kernel error with this error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1703, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 69, in post
    model = yield maybe_future(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 100, in start_kernel_for_session
    kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
    kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 185, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 313, in start_kernel
    self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 220, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 131, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'R'
```

What am I missing here? I'm fairly new to jupyter and programming in general.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Terminal

   ```
   $ jupyter kernelspec list
   ```
2. Go to the dir of irkennel

   ```
   $ cd 'THE_PATH_OF_IRKENNEL'
   ```
3. Remove the json file 'kernel.json' and restart jupyter notebook